# Should zookeeper be run on the worker machines or independent machines?

Tags: solr, hbase, apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

We have several kinds of software that use zookeeper like Solr, Storm, Kafka, Hbase etc.

There are 2 options to install zookeeper cluster (more than 1 nodes):

1. **Embedded cluster**: Install ZK on some of the same machines as the other software are installed OR
2. **External cluster**: Have a few not very powerful but dedicated zookeeper machines (in the same region, cloud and data-center though) to run zookeeper on.

Which is a better option for cluster stability? Note that in both the cases, we always have an odd number of machines in our zookeeper cluster and not just one machine.

It appears that the embedded option is easier to setup and is a better use of the machines but the external option seems more stable because a loss of single machine means the loss of just one component (Loss of a machine in embedded zookeeper means loss of zookeeper node as well as the worker node of Solr, Storm, Kafka whatever the case maybe).

What is the industry standard to run zookeepers in production for maximum stability?

Answer (score 1):

Zookeeper is a critical component for a Kafka cluster but since the implementation of the new generation of clients the load on ZK has been greatly reduced and is now only used by the cluster itself. Even though the load is usually not very high, it can be sensitive to latency and therefore the best practice is to run a Zookeeper ensemble on dedicated machines and optimally even use dedicated disks for ZK transaction logs to avoid IO contention.

By using larger Zookeeper ensembles you gain resiliency but this also increase communication within the cluster and you could lose some performance. Since Zookeeper works with simple majority voting you need an odd number of nodes for it to make sense. A 3 node ensemble allow losing 1 node without impact, a 5 node ensemble allow losing 2 nodes and so on.

In practice, I´ve seen small, low workload clusters run very well with Zookeeper installed on the same machines as the Kafka nodes but if you aim for maximum stability and have increasing traffic, separate clusters would be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider yourself discouraged from using internal ZooKeeper in production.

Its good to have external zookeeper, Best if Zookeeper ensemble(two or more) 
If you have one zookeeper node and it might create problems when it goes down.

if you have cluster setup of zookeeper nodes and if one zookeeper node goes down the remaining majority nodes are running will continue to work.

[More details](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Setting+Up+an+External+ZooKeeper+Ensemble)

Answer (score 0):

For SolrCloud, we strongly recommend that Zookeeper is external, and that you have at least three of them.

This does NOT mean that it cannot run on the same servers as Solr, but it DOES mean that you should *NOT* use the zookeeper server that Solr itself can start, embedded within itself.

Here's some information related to performance and SolrCloud that touches on zookeeper:

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems#SolrCloud

Whether or not you need completely separate machines, or even separate disks for the zookeeper database when running on the same machine as Solr, is *VERY* dependent on the characteristics of your SolrCloud install.  If your index is very small and your query load is low, it's possible that you can put zookeeper on the same machines and even the same disks.

For the other services you mentioned, I have no idea what the recommendation is.